# Roots of a equation on a complex plane

Tags: complex-numbers

How do you get the roots of the equation in algebraic form?
I have no idea after changing to a trigonometric form.
The angle was not simple.

$z^4- \sqrt3 i+1=0$

Comment: But the angle _is_ simple. Look again.

Comment: $z^4=2(\ldots)$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint**: We have $$z^4 =\sqrt {3}i-1 =2 (\frac {\sqrt {3}}{2}i-\frac {1}{2}) =2 (\cos 120^\circ +i \sin 120^\circ) $$

Can you take it from here?

Comment: Yes, I got the answer. thanks.